# How create partitions with custom layout in VM on Xen Server?

Tags: linux, xenserver, supermicro, xen

We use XenServer with RAID 0, as one disk only (I wonder if this is a good approach, if not what would be ?), then we install Xen. After that we put the centOS 6.4 x64 DVD in the server and try to install it. But when it should came the option to create a custom layout of the partitions, it don't. So when we choose the 'use entire disk', the OS start to be installed, and then create the default layout. With `/home` bigger than `/` which we don't want to do that.

I wonder if this is a problem with :

raid or
xenserver or
xenclient or
centos ?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve my problem choosing the 'other media', when it shows the menu to choose which OS you wanna install.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a production system I wouldn't recommend using RAID0. If you want to expand the available storage later but have all storage appear in one pool, LVM would be the best way to go.

I'm not sure what you mean by "when it should came to the option to create a custom layout of the partitions, it don't." Are you using the text installer or the graphical installer? CentOS has removed the ability to specify custom partitioning in the text installer, so if you want to specify your own partitioning scheme you have to use the GUI installer. It is also possible to start the installation with the text installer and connect to the installer via VNC to proceed with a GUI installation.

If you're confused as to how to specify custom partitions in the GUI installer, [this page](http://www.tecmint.com/centos-6-3-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-screenshots/) explains how to install CentOS via the GUI complete with custom partitioning.

So, to answer your final question, this is an issue with the CentOS installer.